# C# return data differ formatting from T-SQL exec for decimal and DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using the following code to call a stored procedure to insert data into a DataTable:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

 SqlConnection scConn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");

 SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter("Store_Procedure_Name", scConn);
 sd.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 sd.Fill(dt);
```

Result set execute in through T-SQL is as below :

```
UserId is int , PurchaseDate is DateTime and Amount is Decimal(20,2)

| UserId | PurchaseDate             | Amount
| 1      | 2019-10-31 00:00:57.617  | 35.00
```

In some how after C# calling through the code above, I inspect the DataTable of C#, the data is different.

```
| UserId | PurchaseDate            | Amount
| 1      | 2019-10-31 00:00:57 SA  | 35,00
```

I have checked both my SQL Server and my local PC region is the same which is United States .

The code is applied in a web application, I have no idea how the SA was appended to the DataTable PurchaseDate as well as why the Amount value from (dot). Become a (comma), I believe it might be the culture problem but I have go through both machine region and culture setting is the same.

Wondering if anyone has been facing the same issue before?

Comment: This purely looks like a formatting issue; the data isn't different it just based on the user language.

Comment: @Larnu both language pc and server language is same

Comment: Dates and numbers are binary values, they have no format. Formats apply only when they are converted to strings for display. How did you display that data?

Comment: Well if you look at the column's data type when debugging your code it will tell you the data type, it should still be int, DateTime and decimal if what you say is true

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos have not apply any format yet , during the datatable fill the formatting is already different , i inspected sd.fill(dt) to check on the data

Comment: If you see `,` as the decimal separator, it means that the PC does *not* use US regional settings. Or the *end user* doesn't use US settings. You didn't explain what kind of application you build. In a web application, the end user's preferred language is used to determine the correct regional settings

Comment: @abccba again, there are no formats. Formats apply when you create the strings. What you posted here is a *string*, not the binary or hex digits of a DateTime or Decimal value. When you displayed those values, they were formatted using the user's locale

Comment: Try to use CultureInfo and see what's going on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: What are you using to display the results? What are you using to inspect them?

Comment: _i inspected sd.fill(dt)_ even the debugger when you ask it to show that data needs to format it

Comment: @PeterSmith Datetime and decimal

Comment: Is this code for a WebApp or DesktopApp?

Comment: That's the datatype, not the inspection tool. Are the above values in the UI or the debugger?

Comment: @PeterSmith the value is from the debugger

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos both PC is using same regional setting.

Comment: Regardless of server regional settings, the culture info of the thread serving the application can be overridden. This override can cause various display differences of number, dates and other facets based on the settings of the thread's culture..

Comment: @RossBush Thank you , it appear that the thread is not sending the culture of en . Thank you

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure what causes this problem. But to get rid of this problem, you can (as a secondary/temporary solution) converting it to the "nvarchar" data type in your stored procedure. The string data type is one of the most compatible data types for data exchange between different environments and also has no intercepting issue at all.

Comment: I did not mean format data from the presentation layer. I suggest doing that for data transfer purposes only. I will rephrase my answer soon.

Comment: The OP is talking about what the data looks like in their application. You are suggesting that you should send the data as character data. This is never going to be a good idea.

Comment: You are right. Here, the source of the problem was specified, and I have voted the related comments. But, if the solution did not find, this temporary/secondary solution would help. At least until finding a better solution.